# How can I sort multiple two dimensional arrays so that the first row is sorted into bins and the second row is summed up?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am going to have a number of two-dimensional arrays that I would like to summarize into a single two-dimensional array. The first row is composed of doubles that represent mass, while the second row is composed of doubles that represent intensity.

```
//example 1 two-dimensional array 
[145.56, 246.44, 346.55, 204.78]
[14,      30,       58,      49]

//example 2 two-dimensional array 
[151.62, 223.18, 389.78, 266.96]
[67,      56,       23,      47]
```

I would like to summarize the two-dimensional arrays by sorting the mass doubles in the first row into bins of equal length, and then summing the pertinent intensity double up. So, assuming the mass bins had a length of 50, the summarized two-dimensional array using the two examples above would be:

```
//tentative example summarized two-dimensional array
[100-150, 150-200, 200-250, 250-300, 300-350, 350-400]
[14,      67,      135,      47,      58,     23     ]
```

I have so far tried to create a for loop that would first check which bin the mass would fall into by iterating over a nested for loop of the , and then add the intensity to previous intensity values.

```
double binSize = 50;
double[] binArray = new double[someNumberOfBins]
double[] summedIntensities= new double[numberOfTheirSummedIntensities];
for(i=0; i<twoDimensionalArray.GetLength(1); i++){
    double currentMass= twoDimensionalArray[0,i];
    for(j=0; j<binArray.GetLength(1); j++) {
        if(currentMass> (binArray[j] - binSize) && currentMass <= (binArray[j] + binSize)) {
            double currentIntensity = twoDimensionalArray[1,i];
            summedIntensities[j] += currentIntensity;
         }
    }
//somehow combine the binArray with summedIntensities array into a two dimensional array
```

However, there are some problems in the a design of this algorithm. Firstly, I do not know how to set up the binArray so that the numbers in it properly reflect the range of in my two-dimensional arrays. I also am not sure how to combine the binArray with the summedIntensities array into a two-dimensional array, or whether this is even practical for this particular case.

Is there another way of making the binArray that is more fitting with my purpose of creating a summarized two-dimensional array, or are there any other glaring problems with this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my algorithm:

**Note 1:** in result array the first row will be '100', '150', '200'... You can construct a `struct` or use `Dictionary<string,int>` if you want it as "100-149", "150-199"...

**Note 2:** i calculated the interval as [100-149], [150,199], [200,249]... modify last condition to change it if you need to

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] array1 = new double[2, 4] { { 145.56d, 246.44d, 346.55d, 204.78d }, { 14d, 30d, 58d, 49d } };
        double[,] array2 = new double[2, 4] { { 151.62d, 223.18d, 389.78d, 266.96d }, { 67d, 56d, 23d, 47d } };

        double[,] finalArray = DoWork(array1, array2,50);
    }

    private static double[,] DoWork(double[,] arrayLeft, double[,] arrayRight, int binLength)
    {
        //union of arrays
        double[,] newArray = new double[2, arrayLeft.GetLength(1) + arrayRight.GetLength(1)]; //2x8 array
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayLeft.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                newArray[i, j] = arrayLeft[i, j];
            }
            for (int j = arrayLeft.GetLength(1); j < arrayLeft.GetLength(1) + arrayRight.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                newArray[i, j] = arrayRight[i, j-4];
            }
        }

        //sorting first row
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.GetLength(1)-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < newArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (newArray[0, i] > newArray[0, j])
                {
                    double temp0 = newArray[0, j];
                    double temp1 = newArray[1, j];

                    newArray[0, j] = newArray[0, i];
                    newArray[1, j] = newArray[1, i];
                    newArray[0, i] = temp0;
                    newArray[1, i] = temp1;

                }
            }
        }

        //determine the number of bins and their intervals
        double minMass = newArray[0, 0];                            //145.56
        double maxMass = newArray[0, newArray.GetLength(1) - 1];    //389.78

        double minBinLowerValue = 0; //since you're working with mass i ignore the negative values
        while (minBinLowerValue + binLength < minMass) minBinLowerValue += binLength; //100

        double maxBinHigherValue = minBinLowerValue;
        while (maxBinHigherValue < maxMass) maxBinHigherValue += binLength; //400

        double numberOfBins = (maxBinHigherValue - minBinLowerValue) / binLength; //6

        //creation of result array
        double[,] resultArray = new double[2, Convert.ToInt32(numberOfBins)]; //2x6 array

        //fill intervals to first row
        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            resultArray[0, i] = minBinLowerValue + binLength * i;
        }

        //fill the sums
        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < newArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if(resultArray[0,i] <= newArray[0,j] && resultArray[0, i] + binLength > newArray[0, j]) //modify this condition
                {
                    sum += newArray[1, j];
                }
            }
            resultArray[1, i] = sum;
        }

        return resultArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I used a dictionary to store the summed values. The key is a bin number.

*Note: If you want to make your solution better, I would use a class with 2 props (mass and intensity) I did not make this solution because  am not sure if you have the freedom to have a class or if you are stuck with with input you got.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] bins1 = { 145.56, 246.44, 346.55, 204.78 };
            double[] values1 = { 14, 30, 58, 49 };

            double[] bins2 = { 151.62, 223.18, 389.78, 266.96 };
            double[] values2 = { 67, 56, 23, 47 };

            int binSize = 50;

            Dictionary<int, double> summedBins = new Dictionary<int, double>();

            AddValuesToSummedBins(binSize, summedBins, bins1, values1);
            AddValuesToSummedBins(binSize, summedBins, bins2, values2);


        }

        public static void AddValuesToSummedBins(int binSize, Dictionary<int, double> SummedBins, double[] Bins, double[] Values)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (double oneBin in Bins)
            {
                int binSet = binSize * ((int) oneBin / binSize);
                if (!SummedBins.ContainsKey(binSet))
                {
                    SummedBins.Add(binSet, Values[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    SummedBins[binSet] += Values[i];
                }
                i++;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are flexible about your data format, you can use LINQ to do this in a very small amount of code.

You would need to store your data pairs as a class with `Mass` and `Intensity` properties, instead of separate items in a 2D array.

Assuming this class to store your data:

```
public class DataElement
{
    public double Mass { get; set; }
    public double Intensity { get; set; }
}
```

You could use the following function:

```
public List<DataElement> Summarize(IEnumerable<DataElement> data, int range)
{
    return data.GroupBy(de => Math.Floor(de.Mass / range) * range,
                       (range, g) => new DataElement {
                                         Mass = range,
                                         Intensity = g.Sum(d => d.Intensity)
                                     })
                .OrderBy(de => de.Mass)
                .ToList();
}
```

This function takes all of your data as a single `IEnumerable`, and runs it thought LINQ's `GroupBy` function.

The first argument is an expression that determines how to group items together.  For your purpose, I simply round down to the nearest multiple of the `range` argument (50 in your example, but anything should work).

The 2nd argument is an expression that returns the final output of a group, given the key of the group (the rounded down Mass), and the elements that were grouped together.  I just return a new `DataElement` with e `Mass` of the rounded down `Mass`, and an `Intensity` equal to the `Sum` of the `Intentities` of the grouped item.

The result is then sorted by `Mass` before returning the result.

This produces the following output from the input you specified in the question (from LINQPad's `Dump` function):

[image]

---

You could use it like this (available as a [LINQPad file](http://share.linqpad.net/9stx7j.linq)):

```
void Main()
{
    var data1 = new List<DataElement>{
        new DataElement{Mass = 145.56, Intensity = 14},
        new DataElement{Mass = 246.44, Intensity = 30},
        new DataElement{Mass = 346.55, Intensity = 58},
        new DataElement{Mass = 204.78, Intensity = 49},
    };
    var data2 = new List<DataElement>{
        new DataElement{Mass = 151.62, Intensity = 67},
        new DataElement{Mass = 223.18, Intensity = 56},
        new DataElement{Mass = 389.78, Intensity = 23},
        new DataElement{Mass = 266.96, Intensity = 47},
    };  

    var result = Summarize(data1.Concat(data2), 50);
}
```